# FTP to image control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ftp

does any one know how one would download an image file into an image control in asp.net using ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an ASHX handler that sends an FtpWebRequest, copies the response to the HttpResponse, and sets the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: Ok that went way over my head, what is an how do I do an ASHX handler? and copies repsonse to httpresponse? er lost again. content type header? again over my head.. Sorry man

Comment: @Garrith: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx

Comment: Copy the stream from the FtpWebResponse to HttpContext.Response

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-Type; `Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/something");`